# Setting axes.linewidth without changing the rcParams global dict

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphing

So, it seems one cannot do the following (it raises an error, since `axes` does not have a `set_linewidth` method):

```
axes_style = {'linewidth':5}
axes_rect = [0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9]

axes(axes_rect, **axes_style)
```

and has to use the following old trick instead:

```
rcParams['axes.linewidth'] = 5 # set the value globally

... # some code

rcdefaults() # restore [global] defaults
```

Is there an easy / clean way (may be one can set `x`- and `y`- axes parameters individually, etc)?

If no, why?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2557264/7758804) does not work, as it is explained in the comments. I suggest using `spines`.
- As mentioned in a comment by [Czechnology](https://stackoverflow.com/users/523100/czechnology), consider changing the ticks too.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 4))

ax1.set_title('Normal spine and ticks')
ax2.set_title('Adjusted spine and ticks')

# change each spine separately:
# ax.spines['right'].set_linewidth(0.5)

# change all spines
for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
    ax2.spines[axis].set_linewidth(4)

# increase tick width
ax2.tick_params(width=4)

plt.show()
```

[image]

- see more about spines at:

  - http://matplotlib.org/api/spines_api.html
  - http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html

Answer (score 21):

```
plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), linewidth=5)
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there's an easy and clean way to do this.

Calling '**axhline**' and '**axvline**' from an axis instance appears to be the technique endorsed in the MPL Documentation.

In any event, it is simple and gives you fine-grained control over the appearance of the axes.

So for instance, this code will create a plot and color the x-axis green and increase the line width of the x-axis from a default value of "1" to a value of "4"; the y-axis is colored red and the line width of the y-axis is increased from "1" to "8".

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as PLT
fig = PLT.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.axhline(linewidth=4, color="g")        # inc. width of x-axis and color it green
ax1.axvline(linewidth=4, color="r")        # inc. width of y-axis and color it red

PLT.show()
```

The axhline/axvline function accepts additional arguments which ought to allow you do any pretty much whatever you want aesthetically, in particular any of the ~matplotlib.lines.Line2D properties are valid kwargs (e.g., 'alpha', 'linestyle', capstyle, joinstyle).

Comment: Is that MC foreign language training, btw? :)

Comment: At least in the latest version of matplotlib, this code creates an horizontal line at `y=0` and a vertical line at `x=0`. This is not the same as changing the color/thickness of the axes.

Comment: @tiago So it got effectively broken, or not?

Comment: This answer is not clear. This is not changing the axes thickness (as implied) it is simply overlaying a horizontal and vertical coloured line at a default "0" location. The answer misses that positional parameter which is fairly important when plotting date-time axes as "0" is 1970-01-01.

The `ax.spines` answer is a better answer in relation to the OP's question

Answer (score 1):

If you're recursively creating (non-rectangular) axes using pyplot, you can change the linewidth parameter for each ax.

For instance:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize = figsize)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = figsize)
for shape in sf.shapeRecords():
    x = [i[0] for i in shape.shape.points[:]]
    y = [i[1] for i in shape.shape.points[:]]
    ax.plot(x, y, 'k', linewidth=5)
```

For documentation, see [MPL.axes documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) (Scroll down until "Other Parameters" -> **kwargs)

N.B. "If you make multiple lines with one plot command, the kwargs apply to all those lines."

Maybe this solution is related to a different question asked elsewhere, but I found this page looking for a solution to my own problem, so maybe it can help others looking for the same thing.